# For loop storage of output data

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to store the output data from the forloop in the `n.I` matrix at the end of the code, but I am certain that something is wrong with my output matrix. It is giving me all the same values, either 0 or 1. I know that `print(SS)` is outputting the correct values and can see that the forloop is working properly.

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix the matrix, or any way that I am able to store the data from the forloop? Thanks in advance!

```
c=0.2
As=1       
d=1    
d0=0.5
s=0.5
e=0.1       
ERs=e/As    

C2 = c*As*exp(-d*s/d0)               

#Island States (Initial Probability)                   
SS=0                    


for(i in 1:5) {  
  if (SS > 0) { 
    if (runif(1, min = 0, max = 1) < ERs){ 
      SS = 0
    } 
  } 
  else { 
    if (runif(1, min = 0, max = 1) < C2) { 
      SS = 1
    }
  }
print(SS)
} 
n.I=matrix(c(SS), nrow=i, ncol=1, byrow=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The efficient solution here is not to use a loop. It's unnecessary since the whole task can be easily vectorized.

```
Z =runif(100,0,1)
as.integer(x <= Z)
#[1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#[70] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate on what exactly this function means? It seems to be giving me similar values to what the for loop was generating(ie this way works). I'm still new in learning R and have noticed how people seem to avoid using forloops when at all possible. Why is that? Much appreciated Roland!

Comment: You should read "An Introduction to R". This creates 100 random values at once and compares your x value with all of these at once. The resulting logical vector (of TRUE/FALSE values) is then turned into an integer vector (of 1/0 values). Vectorization means that the loop happens in compiled code, which is faster by many orders of magnitude. Vectorized code is usually also much more readable (as this example nicely demonstrates).

Answer (score 0):

you can save them in a list. Not very efficient but gets the job done.
list[[1]] indicates the first element saved in a list if you want to retrieve it.

```
  list_pos  <- list() # create the list out of the for loop
  for(i in 1:100) {
    c=0.10 #colonization rate
    A=10 #Area of all islands(km^2)
    d=250 #Distance from host to target (A-T)
    s=0.1 #magnitude of distance
    d0=100 #Specific "half distance" for dispersal(km)
    C1 = c*A*exp(-d/d0) #Mainland to Target colonization
    Z =runif(1,0,1)
    x <- C1*A


    if(x <= Z) {
            list_pos[[i]]  <-  print("1") # Here you can store the 1 results.print is actually not necessary.
    } 
    if(x >= Z){
            list_pos[[i]]  <- print("0") # Here you can store the 0 results.print is actually not necessary.
    }
 }
```